# docker - how to disable detach key, --detach-keys="" not working

Tags: docker

how to disable detach key?
i have try:

> docker exec -it --detach-keys="" -e TERM=$TERM centos bash -l -i

but it not working

Comment: why do you want to do this? how do you want to detach then?

Comment: @Siyu i usually exec a bash. i only need to exit it , but not detach. i cat exit it use CTRL-d or exit command in bash.
The default detach key conflic with the bash(readline) previous command short cut.  so i want to disable the detach keys.